# Adding contents of a label to contents of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array questionHalf and a next button which invokes a method nextQuestionButton that cycles through the items in the questionHalf array and displays the next string in a label questionLabel

```
questionHalf = @[@"Atlanta", @"Detroit", @"Houston", @"Green Bay", @"San Francisco"];
```

which can be cycled through using a next button:

```
 - (IBAction)nextQuestionButton:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)nextQuestionButton:(id)sender
    {
        if (currentQuestionIndex < [questionHalf count] -1)
            currentQuestionIndex ++;
        else currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        _questionLabel.text = questionHalf [currentQuestionIndex];
    }
```

which is then displayed in a label

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
```

I would now like to add 5 more buttons that let users pick from strings to complete an American Football teams name.

When the user picks I need to see if the combined string is a valid team name.

I have another array correctFullAnswer which contains all the valid full teams names and need to test if the users answer matches one of the answers in this string.

```
correctFullAnswer = @[@"Atlanta Falcons", @"Detroit Lions", @"Houston Texans", @"Green Bay Packers", @"San Francisco 49'ers"];
```

I have also added the first of the 5 required buttons

```
- (IBAction)packersAnswerButton:(id)sender;




- (IBAction)packersAnswerButton:(id)sender
    {
        NSString* selectedTeamName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", questionHalf [currentQuestionIndex], answerHalf];
        if ([correctFullAnswer indexOfObject:selectedTeamName] != NSNotFound)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                [packersAnswerButton.alpha setAlpha:1];
            }
        ];}

        }
```

However I am now getting an error of undeclared identifier 'packersAnswerButton' when i attempt to get the button to hide once correct answer has been selected.

Comment: Your question does not make sense on several levels. You say "I have a label questionLabel... which holds an array questionHalf..." Labels don't hold arrays. Buttons also don't hold strings. View objects display information, not hold information. You also say "evaluates whether this is a correctFullAnswer", but don't define what it means to be a correct answer. Does that mean that a string is a member of the array correctFullAnswer?

Comment: Here's what I think you are saying: "I have an array questionHalf. When the user taps a next button, it invokes a method nextQuestionButton that cycles through the items in the questionHalf array and displays the next string in a label questioLabel. I need to add 5 more buttons that let the user pick from strings to complete team names. When the user picks, I need to test to see if the combined string is a valid team name. I have another array, correctFullAnswer, which contains all the valid full team names, and need to test if the user's answer matches one of these names.

Comment: Please edit your question so it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your comments. What you have described in your second comment is exactly what I mean, I am sorry my question does not accurately reflect this and I will look at editing it to be more accurate. Cheers.

Comment: Whatever you come up with, consider this: concatenating the strings and comparing them is *very* fragile. Far better to have some constants that represent the **index** of the correct answers, for example, for city 1 the correct answer is team name 4. You could then do something like `setTag` on the answer buttons and checking if the button with the correct answer was clicked becomes trivially easy.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your response. I was thinking that there must be a better way of achieving the same results. From what you are saying I am guessing you mean setting the tag of each answer button to a unique number and then comparing whether or not the number of the tag is equal to the index of the object in the question label?

Answer (score 0):

Just add 5 buttons to the view you want to add the buttons. The process is something similar to the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //i'm assuming containerView is the view where you are going to add the buttons
    NSArray* teamNameSuffices = @[@"Falcons", @"Lions", @"Texans", @"Packers", @"49'ers"];
    int i = 0;
    for(NSString* suffix in teamNameSuffices) {
        UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(<%# your required frame coordinates #>);
        btn.titleLabel.text = suffix;
        btn.tag = i;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(suffixSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [containerView addSubview:btn];
        i++;
    }
}

-(void)suffixSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    //here you retrieve suffix text and compare if it is valid team name
    NSString* suffix = sender.titleLabel.text;
    NSString* selectedTeamName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",questionHalf [currentQuestionIndex]/* or _questionLabel.text, whichever is accessible */,suffix];
    if([correctFullAnswer indexOfObject:selectedTeamName] != NSNotFound) { //a valid team name is constructed
        [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!" message:@"Bingo!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
        //or do whatever is required
    }
}
```

Optionally you can also create the suffix buttons from the designer(storyboard/xib), set their titles accordingly and set their targets to `suffixSelected:` method right from their. In that case you need to declare the method as `(IBAction)` rather than `(void)`.

Please let me know if you need to explore anything else.

Comment: Hi Ayan thanks for your quick reply. Ive edited my comment above to cover Button one of the five buttons needed and have attempted to start writing the code for it, however I seem to be getting lost somewhere with it. Also not sure what is applicable in the viewDidLoad section as I'm creating my buttons in storyboard rather than code. If you could have another look that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @AlanBurnell I've already mentioned at the bottom that is you are creating your buttons in designer, you can simply change the signature of `suffixSelected:` method to `-(IBAction) suffixSelected:(UIButton*)sender` and once you are done with that you can connect that method from Connections Inspector to your buttons for Touch Up Inside event. No `viewDidLoad` would required in that case.

Comment: @AlanBurnell as for the error with undeclared identifier is concerned you might have noticed that you are trying to assign an alpha value to a method `packersAnswerButton:` rather than the button itself. It should have been `[(UIButton*)sender setAlpha:0.0];` rather than `[packersAnswerButton.alpha setAlpha:1];`. One quick note, alpha value 0 would hide a button making it transparent rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly for the error you are getting.

By the looks of it you have created the button action. ( IBAction ) And connected the button to the action.

But not may have not have linked the button to a IBoutlet.

Which when done you would use it to set the buttons properties.

I.e

```
@property IBOutlet (nonatomic) UIButton  packersButton;
```

Have a look at this apple doc [Interface Builder help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html)